# Converting Vertex color to Material with BDSF Shader

Tags: materials, shaders

My initial question is that when I hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to add a node, shaders don't come up as an option.  How do I add a BSDF shader if none of them are appearing at all/am I in the wrong viewport?

Second, what alterations do I make to the node so that the vertex colors from my model will upload to unity?

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to guess what is wrong with adding shader nodes in your example without any screenshots. Shader nodes can only be added in material nodes so maybe that's the problem. Vertex colors have nothing to do with materials and are added with mesh itself. Though it's a separate question and it's unclear what the desired output is

Comment: Please ask your second question about exporting to unity as a separate question.